# linear equivalent min{} constraint

Tags: linear-programming, convex-optimization

Activities are assigned to venues. Each activity $a_i$ has maximum size $b_i$ and demand $c_i$. Each venue $v_j$ has maximum size $d_j$.

An activity can be assigned to multiple venues, and we need to make sure that the total capacity is at least as great as the demand for each venue.

Denote $X_{i,j}$ to be $1$ if activity $i$ is assigned to venue $j$, or $0$ otherwise.

The constraint:
$$
\sum_{j}X_{i,j} \times \text{min}\{b_i, d_j\} \geq c_i \quad \forall i
$$
ensures that the demand is satisfied from the effective capacity (the minimum of the activity/venue capacity pair).

What I actually want to do is to store these results in a set of variable $Y_i$ representing the total capacity for activity $a_i$ so that I can use it elsewhere in my model.

$$
Y_i = \sum_{j}X_{i,j} \times \text{min}\{b_i,d_j\} \quad \forall i \\
Y_i \geq c_i \quad \forall i
$$

How can I write this without a $\text{min}\{\}$ function?

Answer (score 0):

Store the $min\{b_i,d_j\}$ in an another variable say $Z_{ij}=min\{b_i,d_j\}$ and use
$$Y_i = \sum_j X_{i,j} \times Z_{ij}, \forall i$$ $$Y_i \geq c_i $$

Comment: I... suppose. But this only half solves the problem. When I said I had to use the $Y_i$ later, I have another $\text{min}\{\}$ which has a variable as one of the elements. So basically I still need to know the linear equivalent form for this expression.